# Fortran code returns 0 for every calculation in the loop

Tags: fortran

Can anyone help me to find where I am going wrong about writing this code

```
    program time_period
    ! This program calculates time period of an SHM given length of the chord
    implicit none
    integer, parameter:: length=10
    real, parameter :: g=9.81, pi=3.1415926535897932384
    integer, dimension(1:length)::chordlength
    integer :: l
    real :: time
    do l= 1,length
    time = 2*pi*(chordlength(l)/(g))**.5
    print *, l, time
    enddo
    end program
```

Result:

```
1 0.00000000E+00
2 0.00000000E+00
3 0.00000000E+00
4 0.00000000E+00
5 0.00000000E+00
6 0.00000000E+00
7 0.00000000E+00
8 0.00000000E+00
9 0.00000000E+00
10 0.00000000E+00
```

[image: Screenshot of code and result]

Comment: You haven't given any value to the array `chordlength`.

Comment: shouldn't it assume values in the increments of 1?

Comment: No.  If you want it to have certain values, you'll have to specify those.  If you want help with that, please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to generate a table that has chord lengths from 1 to 10 and against each entry associated time period of the SHM.. i am not looking to type the length manually

Comment: Why is `chordlength` an integer? Shouldn't length be a real number?

Comment: I will also note that the value of pi you give has many more digits than are representable by a single-precision real (good to 6 or 7 decimal digits). It probably doesn't matter here, but keep it in mind in the future. Also note that the form of the constant you show is single precision, no matter what the declared kind of the variable or PARAMETER. Lastly, I'd recommend using parentheses in the line 11 expression and avoiding mixed-mode arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

If the chord lengths you're interested are the integer values `1,2,...,10` you hardly need an array to store them.  Further, if what you are interested in are the SHM period lengths for each of those 10 chord lengths, it strikes me that you should have an array like this:

```
real, dimension(length) :: shm_periods
```

which you would then populate, perhaps like this:

```
do l= 1,length
    shm_periods(l) = 2*pi*(l/g)**.5
    print *, l, shm_periods(l)
enddo
```

Next, you could learn about Fortran's *array syntax* and write only one statement to assign values to `shm_periods`.

Answer (score 1):

@High Performance Mark

i worked it the following way

```
program time_period
! This program calculates time period of an SHM given length of the chord
implicit none
integer, parameter:: length=10
real, parameter :: g=9.81, pi=3.1415926535897932384
integer, dimension(1:length)::chordlength
integer :: l
real, dimension(1:length) :: timeperiod

  do l= 1,length
  print *, 'Enter ChordLength', l
  read *, chordlength(l)
  timeperiod(l) = 2*pi*(chordlength(l)/g)**.5
  enddo
  do l=1,length
  print *, l, timeperiod(l)
  enddo
  end program
```

its giving me results but asking to type the chord lengths...appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `real, dimension(1:length)::chordlength` instead?

Comment: i could do that in the next one...it was just to get an understanding ..thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Why do you need an array for `chordlength` if it is going to be inputted each time? Your code looks like it was intended to process 10 length values that are read from a file or inputted all together in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does not answer your question (since you already did that). But it does address some issues with the design of the code.

As a next step, lets say you want to use a) a function for the calculation, b) have some standard length values to display the period and c) input a custom length for calculation.

Fortran allows for the declaration of `elemental` functions which can operate on single values or arrays just the same (with no need for a loop). See the example below:

```
elemental function CalcTimePeriod(chord_length) result(period)
! Calculate the SHM time period from the chord length   
real, parameter :: g=9.80665, pi=3.1415926535897932384
real, intent(in) :: chord_length
real :: period

    period = 2*pi*sqrt(chord_length/g)

end function
```

So I am posting the code below in hopes that you can learn something new with modern Fortran.

[image: scr]

```
program SHM_CalcTime
implicit none

! Variables
integer, parameter :: n = 10
real, dimension(n) :: gen_lengths, periods
real :: input_length
integer :: i

! Example calculation from generated array of chord lengths
! fill an array of lengths using the formula len = 1.0 + (i-1)/2
gen_lengths = [ (1.0+real(i-1)/2, i=1, n) ]
! calculate the time periods for ALL the lengths in the array
periods = CalcTimePeriod(gen_lengths)

write (*, '(1x,a14,1x,a18)') 'length', 'period'
do i=1,n
    write (*, '(1x,g18.4,1x,g18.6)') gen_lengths(i), periods(i)
end do
input_length = 1.0
do while( input_length>0 )
    write (*,*) 'Enter chord length (0 to exit):'
    read (*,*) input_length
    if(input_length<=0.0) then
        exit
    end if
    write (*, '(1x,g18.4,1x,g18.6)') input_length, CalcTimePeriod(input_length)        
end do

contains

elemental function CalcTimePeriod(chord_length) result(period)
! Calculate the SHM time period from the chord length   
real, parameter :: g=9.80665, pi=3.1415926535897932384
real, intent(in) :: chord_length
real :: period

    period = 2*pi*sqrt(chord_length/g)

end function

end program SHM_CalcTime
```

On a final note, see that programs can have internal functions declared after a `contains` statement, with no need for an explicit interface declaration as you would with older Fortran variants.